# Getting Messagebox To Mention Specific Column

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a simple code to highlight the last used row in an Excel column. Thing is, I want to get the messagebox to mention the column in question- is it possible to do this? For instance I have used column A here, and would like the messagebox to display "The last non-used row in column A is ", likewise if I changed LR to column B, C etc.

```
Sub lastrowcolumn()
Dim LR As Integer
   LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   Outcome = MsgBox("The last non-used row in column is" & " " & LR)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last row or column on a sheet you can always do Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count or Sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

You can this to get the column of a certain cell or range:

```
Split(Columns(Cells(1, 30).Column).Address(False, False), ":")
```

Column of a cell:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim Col() As String

    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Col = Split(Columns(Cells(1, 30).Column).Address(False, False), ":")
    MsgBox ("The last non-used cell is in column " & Col(0) & " row " & LR)
End Sub
```

Column of a range:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim Col() As String

    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Col = Split(Columns(Range("A:C").Columns.Count).Address(False, False), ":")
    MsgBox ("The last non-used cell is in column " & Col(0) & " row " & LR)
End Sub
```

Last column in a sheet:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim Col() As String

    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Col = Split(Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Address(False, False), ":")
    MsgBox ("The last non-used cell is in column " & Col(0) & " row " & LR)
End Sub
```

-Edit-

Last unused column:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim Col() As String

    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'Col = Split(Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1).Address(False, False), ":")
    'Alternative method to get column number
    Col = Split(Columns(ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address(False, False), ":")
    MsgBox ("The last non-used cell is in column " & Col(0) & " row " & LR)
End Sub
```

Last unused row:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim Col() As String

    LR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    Col = Split(Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1).Address(False, False), ":")
    MsgBox ("The last non-used cell is in column " & Col(0) & " row " & LR)
End Sub
```

Comment: My bad Ripster, I wanted the last non-used row of the column. I guess it's just tweaking the second code you provided?

Comment: Yes, I posted an edit. Hopefully that is what you were looking for!

Comment: Hi Ripster, that code is perfect apart from I had previously entered something into a cell outside the range of the data, and even though I had deleted that value the messagebox took that into account when searching through the columns. I had to delete the empty columns in excel before getting the correct answer- is there a way round this? I can live with this though.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure because this does not seem to be an issue for me. You could try Columns(ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1 to get the last column instead.

Comment: I added an alternative in my example above. I hope that works correctly for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Private Const c_lVeryLastRow As Long = 1048577

'Worksheet_SelectionChange event
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lFirstUnusedRow As Long

    lFirstUnusedRow = ActiveSheet.Range(Target.Address).End(xlDown).Row + 1
    If lFirstUnusedRow = c_lVeryLastRow Then
        If (Target.Value = "") Then
            lFirstUnusedRow = ActiveSheet.Range(Target.Address).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Target.Row
        Else
            lFirstUnusedRow = Target.Row + 1
        End If
    End If
    Call MsgBox(CStr(lFirstUnusedRow))
End Sub
```